# Confirmatory structural equation modelling to test predicted strengths of relationships?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have two implicit measures (impl. attitude towards high-cal food and alcohol) and two explicit measures (high-cal food consumption and alcohol consumption). I want to confirm that my implicit measures map on their relevant explicit measures, more strongly than cross-substance.

I was thinking of specifying a SEM model in lavaan where the cross-substance relationships are fixed to be half as strong as the within-substance relationships, which are set to be equally strong, and compare these with a model where all relationships are set to be equally strong.

How would I specify these two models in lavaan?

[image: The two models I intend to specify and compare in lavaan]

And, on a more theoretical level: is this a good way to test my hypothesis? Would there be better ways to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add parameter constraints, to make some parameters equal (or give them a fixed ratio of .5)

In lavaan, if you label a parameter and provide the same label for multiple parameters then lavaan will set those parameters to be equal.

The following model statement will set parameter constraints such that all coefs are equal (I've given them the label "a"):

```
model_all_equal <- "
alc_consumption ~ a*alc_att + a*hi_cal_att
hiCal_consumption ~ a*alc_att + a*hi_cal_att
"
```

In the case when you want parameters to have some ratio, you can add different parameter labels and then add explicit constraints, like this:

```
Model_not_all_equal <- "
alc_consumption ~ a*alc_att + b*hi_cal_att
hiCal_consumption ~ b*alc_att + a*hi_cal_att
a = 2*b
"
```

In the above model, the parameters labeled a will be the same, the parameters labeled b will be the same, and b will be equal to one half of a.

Hopefully this gives you enough to play around with other possible model constraints